# Theorem 2.1.7 of Durrett, Probability Theory and Examples (4TH Edition)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Theorem 2.1.7 states that "Suppose $X_1,..., Xn$" are independent random variables and $X_i$ has distribution $\mu_i$, then $(X_1,..., X_n)$ has distribution $\mu_1\times...\times\mu_n$. The proof shows $P((X_1,...,X_n)\in A_1\times...\times A_n)=\mu_1(A_1)\times...\times \mu_n(A_n)=(\mu_1\times...\times \mu_n)(A_1\times...\times A_n)$ (here I understand). Then it says since $A_1\times...\times A_n$ is a $\pi$ system that generates $R^n$, then by applying $\pi-\lambda$ theorem we have the result. I wonder specifically how the theorem is applied here?

Comment: What is the $\pi - \lambda$ theorem?

Comment: If $P$ is a $\pi$ system and $L$ is a $\lambda$ system that contains $P$ then $\sigma(P)\subset L$

Comment: Hint: Take $L$ to be the class of sets $B$ in the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B^{\otimes n}$ such that $P((X_1,\ldots,X_n)\in B)=(\mu_1\times\cdots\times\mu_n)(B)$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins could you show me how to prove if $A, B\in L$, and $A\subset B$, then $B-A\in L$ in this case?